# Powershell Script Adds massive number of Network Printers

Tags: powershell, printing, network-printers

Printers at my job are in constant flux. Because of this I need a script that can automate the process of adding and deleting printers with little intervention. I have here an example of the code that I am using to perform this task. I'd like to condense this code and add 2 new features, unfortunately my ability to code is few an far between as I am but a humble systems janitor.

New Feature idea's:

1. If the .vbs files 'Last Modified' date has not been altered since the last time this script was ran, the script immediately stops. A comment outlining a method to override this would be good too.
2. The log file that shows which servers were created, I'd like to know if they were created -successfully- or if they failed.

If the script comes across an error while adding a network printer, it will immediately skip it, but the log will show that the printer has been added created

```
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
     Printer Script
     1. Archives the working file if it is greater than or equal to 1 MB
     2. Starts logging
     3. Removes priners which no longer exist on the print server (because of deletion, moves, etc) in a status of 2
     4. Compares the Network printer list to the locally installed Network printers and outputs a list of the printers not installed locally
     5. Takes the new printer list, and pings each printer, if ping fails, the printer is removed from the install list
     6. Builds new printers
     7. Ends logging
     8. Performs log file maintenance by archiving and removing old log files


    .DESCRIPTION
    Date: 04/03/2013
    Version: 1
    PowerShell Version: 2.0

    .INPUTS
    Network Printer Script \\ShareDrive\Sharefolder\ShareFile.vbs

    .OUTPUTS
    Log files
    Archive files
    Temp text files 
       ShareFile.txt
       pl.txt
       Localprinters.txt
       NewPrinters.txt
       ToDelete.txt
       working.txt

    .EXAMPLE
    C:\scripts\PrinterMaint.ps1

    .NOTES
    Create the following folders before running this script:
    C:\PrinterMaint\
    C:\temp\
    C:\Scripts\

    .LINK


    #>

###################
####-VARIABLES-####
###################

    # Get computer name
    $Server = (gc env:computername)

    # Specifies Local Printer Properties to be retrieved
    $Props = "Name","PrinterStatus"

    $GLOBAL:job1 = ""

    # Log file naming convention
    $Logfile = "C:\PrinterMaint\"+$(gc env:computername)+".log"

    # Archive log naming convention
    $archive = "C:\PrinterMaint\Archive_"+(gc env:computername)+"_"+$date2+".log"

    # Gets todays date and assigns it to a variable
    $date = Get-Date

    # temp files and path of text file which holds the names of the printers to be deleted
    $DelFile = "C:\temp\ToDelete.txt"

    # Creates a formatted date which can be used in a file name
    $date2 = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-ddTHHmmss"

    # Error File
    $ErrorFile = "C:\PrinterMaint\Errors.log"

    # Handle Errors
    $ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"

    # Get computer name
     $Server = (gc env:computername)

    # Local Printer
     $GOBAL:LPrinter = @()

     $GLOBAL:ltext = @()

     $GLOBAL:FinalPrinters = @()

     $GLOBAL:Bad = @()


###################
####-FUNCTIONS-####
###################

    Function ServiceShutdown #Shuts down High CPU services while this script runs so as to not interfere
    {
        Set-Service SAVAdminService -StartupType Disabled
        Stop-Service SAVAdminService
        Set-Service SavService -StartupType Disabled
        Stop-Service SavService
    }

     Function CycleSpooler
    {
        Write-Host "Cycling Print Spooler"
        Stop-Service spooler
        Start-Sleep -seconds 10
        Start-Service spooler
        Write-Host "Print Spooler Cycle is complete"
    }

     Function ServiceReenable
    {
        Set-Service SavService -StartupType Automatic
        Start-Service SavService
        Set-Service SAVAdminService -StartupType Automatic
        Start-Service SAVAdminService
    }

    Function GetLocalPrinters
    {
        # Start gathering local printer info
        $GLOBAL:job1 = gWmi Win32_Printer -computer $Server -Property $props -AsJob

        If ($GLOBAL:job1.State -eq "Running")
        {
            Cls
            Write-Host "The local Printer gather may take several minutes to complete" -ForegroundColor Blue -BackgroundColor Yellow
            $i = 0

            do {Write-Progress -Activity "Gathering Local Printers..." -status "$i seconds";$i+=5; Start-sleep -seconds 5}
            while ($GLOBAL:job1.State -eq "Running")
            Write-Progress "Done" "Done" -completed

    Else
        {Write-Host "Local printer gather has completed" -ForegroundColor Yellow}
     }
    }

    Function ArchiveLog # Archives log files if they are greater than or equal to 1MB
    {
    # Creates the Variable which will hold the archive log naming convention


    if (test-path $Logfile) #If the logfile exists then determine if it needs to be archived
    {
        # Gets the log file if it is greater than oe equal to 1MB
        Get-ChildItem $LogFile -recurse | ? {($_.length/1MB) -ge 1} | % {

            # Archives the log File
            Move-Item $_.Fullname $archive
        }
    }
       else # If the log file does not exist
        {New-Item $Logfile -type File} # Create a new log file
    }

    Function LogI # Function Called to Write actions to the log file
    {
       # Accepts the parameter
       Param ([string]$logstring)

       # new line
       "`r`n"

       # Logs variable to the log file
       $logstring >> $LogFile
    }

    Function StartLog # Function called to format the beginning of each log file
    {
        LogI "**********Starting Log**********"
        LogI  "Log Date: $(Get-Date)"
    }

    Function EndLog # Function called to format the end of each log file
    {
        LogI "**********End Log**********"
        LogI  "Log Date: $(Get-Date)"
    } 


    Function CleanupTMP # Function called to cleanup all temp files created by this script
    {
        # Cleanup of existing build files
        $workingfiles = "C:\temp\ShareFile.txt", "C:\temp\pl.txt", "C:\temp\Localprinters.txt", "C:\temp\NewPrinters.txt", "C:\temp\ToDelete.txt", "C:\temp\working.txt"

    foreach ($file in $workingfiles) # Gets each file, deletes it 
        { 
        # Determines if the file in the path exists
         if (test-path $file) 

          { 
            echo Test-Path $file
            # If the file does exist, it deletes each one
            Remove-Item $file 

            # Writes the name of the deleted file to the log file
            LogI "Deleted File: $date $file" 
          }

        }
     }

    Function CleanupLogs # Removes Log files older than 14 days old
    {
        # set folder path
        $log_path = "C:\PrinterMaint\Archive*.log" 

        # set min age of files to 14 days
        $max_days = "-14"

        # determine how far back we go based on current date
        $del_date = $date.AddDays($max_days) 

        # Gets log files older than the $max_days defiled and Removes them
        Get-ChildItem $log_path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date } | Remove-Item
        }

        Function BadPrinter # Function checks for indtalled printers with a status of 2, "Printer not Found on Server, unable to connect"
        {
        # Handle Bad Printers

        # Gathers Printers with status of 2 - Not Found on Server
        $GLOBAL:Bad = $GLOBAL:LPrinters | where {$_.printerstatus -eq 2} | select name | sort name
        #$GLOBAL:Bad2 = $GLOBAL:LPrinters | where {$_.printerstatus -eq 3 -and $_.name -ne "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"} | select name | sort name
        #$GLOBAL:Bad = $GLOBAL:Bad1 + $GLOBAL:Bad2

        if ($GLOBAL:Bad.count -gt 0) # If the array is greater than 0 then call the function to delete the printers
            {DelPrinter}

        Else
            {Write-Host "No printers will be deleted" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            LogI "$date No printers were deleted"}
    }

    Function DelPrinter # Function is called to delete printers if the array tests to be greater than 0
    {
        # Outputs the printers to a text file
        $GLOBAL:Bad | Out-File $DelFile

        # Assigns the text file contents to an array
        $btext = gc $DelFile

        # Removes the text file
        #remove-item $DelFile

    ##########################-Formatting-##########################################
    # Remove first four lines from the text file, spaces and blank lines
        $btext[0],$btext[3..($btext.length-1)] | out-file $DelFile -encoding ascii
        (gc $DelFile) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | sc $DelFile -encoding ascii
        (gc $DelFile) | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()} | sc $DelFile -encoding ascii
        (gc $DelFile) | where {$_ -ne ""} | sc $DelFile -encoding ascii
    ##########################-Formatting-###########################################

    # Removing a Network Printer Connection
    # Get the contents of the delete text file
    $GLOBAL:Bad = (gc $DelFile)

    # Reviews each item in the array and processes them seperately
    foreach ($B in $Bad)
    {
        # Reinitializes date for more accurate reporting
        $date2 = Get-Date

        # Assigns the date and time to the printer being deleted to a variable
        $LogDel = "$date2 $B"

        # Logs the deletion of the printer
        LogI "Deleted: $LogDel"

        # Networked printer is now deleted
        Write-Host "Deleting printer $B"
        (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemovePrinterConnection("$B")
     }
    }

    Function GNP # Function to Get Network Printers (GNP)
    {
        # Copies the printer map script to the local computer
        Copy-Item \\ShareDrive\Sharefolder\ShareFile.vbs C:\temp\ShareFile.txt
    }

    Function FNP
    {
        # Assign the contents of the Network printer list to a variable
            $NPrinters = Get-Content C:\temp\ShareFile.txt
    ##########################-Formatting-##########################################
        #removes all text and formatting from the network printer list then assigns the contents to a new array
        foreach ($NPrinter in $NPrinters) 
            {
                $NPrinter1 = $NPrinter.split(" ")
                $Printers = $NPrinter1[1]
                $Printers1 = $($Printers -split '"')
                $PL = $Printers1[1]|Where-Object {$_.length -gt 2}
                $PL >> C:\temp\pl.txt
            }
    ##########################-Formatting-########################################## 
     }

     Function GIP
     {
        # Get the installed printers and write to a file
        $GLOBAL:LPrinters | select name | sort name  | Out-File C:\temp\LocalPrinters.txt

        # Get the contents of the file and load into an array
         $GLOBAL:ltext = gc C:\temp\Localprinters.txt

        # Remove the old file
        remove-item C:\temp\Localprinters.txt
     }

     Function FIP
     {    

      # Format the data in the array by removing the  first four lines and spaces from the array and output to the file
       $GLOBAL:ltext[0],$GLOBAL:ltext[3..($GLOBAL:ltext.length-1)] | out-file C:\temp\Localprinters.txt -encoding ascii

         # Removes blanks from the file and sets the contents with the new formatting
     (gc C:\temp\Localprinters.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | sc C:\temp\Localprinters.txt -encoding ascii

     # Removes the blank lines from the end of the file and sets the contents with the new formatting
     (gc C:\temp\Localprinters.txt) | ForEach {$_.trimEnd()} | sc C:\temp\Localprinters.txt -encoding ascii

     # Assigns the nice neat contents of the file back to the array
     $GLOBAL:ltext = (gc C:\temp\Localprinters.txt)
    }

     Function COMP
     {
    # Begins comparing the two printer files
        # Compares the files and outputs non-built printers to the NewPrinters.txt file
          $FinalGroups = Compare-Object (gc C:\temp\pl.txt) (gc C:\temp\LocalPrinters.txt) |
            where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} |
            select -ExpandProperty inputObject |
            sort
            #Removes duplicate printers from the list using the -uniq
            $FinalGroups | select -uniq | Out-File C:\temp\NewPrinters.txt
            $GLOBAL:FinalPrinters = gc C:\temp\NewPrinters.txt
     }

     Function PNP
     {
    # Test new printer connectivity

    $PingFile = "C:\temp\NewPrinters.txt"
    $PingFile
    $Pings = gc $PingFile

    # Get just the printer names from the New Print File and appends them to a new file called Working
        foreach ($p in $Pings)
        {
             $np = $p.split("\\")
             $to = $np[3]
             $to >> C:\temp\working.txt
        }
    # Assigns the contents of the working file (new printers) to an array
        $to = gc C:\temp\working.txt

        foreach ($t in $to)
            {

                # Tests the printers connection
                 write-host "testing printer $t"
                 $ok = Test-Connection $t -Count 2 -Quiet
                #Takes the connectivity results and determines to remove the printer from the file prior to build starting.  
                 if ($ok -ne "TRUE")
                    {
                        write-host "$t Communication Failed" -ForegroundColor Red
                        # If the printer communication fails, the entry is removed from the NewPrinters.txt file
                        (gc "C:\temp\NewPrinters.txt") -notmatch "$t" | Out-file "C:\temp\NewPrinters.txt"

                        # Logs the removal of the printer and why it is being removed
                        #Reinitializes date for more accurate times in the log file
                        $date11 = Get-Date
                        $remprt = "$date11 - printer $t will not be built - communication failed"
                        LogI $remprt
                    }

                else
                    {
                        Write-Host "$t Communication Successful" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                    }
             }
    }

    Function BUILD
    {
    # Build each new printer found in the NewPrinters text file
        $ToBuild = gc C:\temp\NewPrinters.txt
        foreach ($item in $ToBuild)
         {

            # Reinitialized date to get more accurate reporting
                $date4 = Get-Date
            # Creates Logging info
                $LogIt = "Created: $date4 $item"

            # Calls function to write information to a log file
                LogI $LogIt 

                Write-Host -NoNewLine "Creating printer $item" -ForegroundColor green
            # Printer Build now occurs
                (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection("$item")
        }
    }

##############
####-MAIN-####
##############

    # Cleanup High CPU and long running services which interfere with this script
    ServiceShutdown

    # Cycle the print spooler service    
    CycleSpooler

    # Get Local Printers
    GetLocalPrinters

    # Archive log maintenance
    ArchiveLog

    # Starts logging
    StartLog

    # Get the completed job
  `enter code here`  $GLOBAL:LPrinters = Receive-Job -job $GLOBAL:job1 -keep | select $props

    # Handles Bad pritners in a status of 2 "Printer not Found on Server, unable to connect"
    BadPrinter

    # Get Network printer list
    GNP

    # Format Network printer list
    FNP

    # Get installed/existing printers
    GIP

    # Format installed/existing printer file
    FIP

    # Compare existing printers with new printers only keep network printers needing to be built
    COMP

    # Check if New Printer File is NULL
    if ($GLOBAL:FinalPrinters.count -gt 0)
        {
            # Ping new printer connection and remove printers with failed connections
              PNP

            # Build new printers
              BUILD
        }
    Else
        {
            $date6 = Get-Date
            LogI "$date6 No new printers were built"
        }

    # Cleanup temp text files
    CleanupTMP

    # Stops Logging
    EndLog

    # Cleanup Archive log files older than the specified ## of days
    CleanupLogs

    # Restarts Services    
    ServiceReenable

    # Cycle the print spooler service    
    CycleSpooler

    # Printer Maintenance is Complete
    Write-Host "Printer Maintenance is complete" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Yellow
```

## Example of what is inside the VBS:

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\PrintServer\Printer1"
```

I do not control nor maintain this file. I am only allowed to run it. This script copies the .vbs to a local text file which is then edited as needed.

Comment: So you've given us a ton of code, which is Great! but it's a bit hard to see exactly what your having trouble getting to work.  You list the feature ideas but I don't see any attempt in the code to implement them.  We're here to help you work past problems in your code, not create it for you.  Please take a look at the `Get-Item` cmdlet and `if/else` statements and see if you can make any progress towards the features you would like created and let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: Oh no! The code works! it works great! It's, as you mentioned... huge. I haven't implemented the 'new feature' code anywhere, which is the part i'd like help with.

Comment: Ok, have you tried anything yet to get it to work with those new features?  Did you take a look at `Get-Item`?  We're more than happy to help you work past problems but we're not here to just write new code for you.  Please make an attempt at adding the features and let us know what you come up with/what you have trouble with.

Comment: SO is not a code (re-)writing service. Please try to implement it yourself and come back when you have a *specific* question about something you can't get to work. Make code you post a [mcve].